# googleVis sankey-diagrams not displaying correctly

Tags: r, googlevis, sankey-diagram

I was able to create a Sankey-diagram. However, when rendered only half of the plot appears in the web browser:

[image]

Any ideas on how to correctly render the plot without leaving the R language too much?

Code bellow replicates the chart:

```
library(reshape2)
library(googleVis)

#Download the file at:
#https://ben.epe.gov.br/downloads/Matriz%20Energ%c3%a9tica%20Nacional%20ab2014.xlsx

#importing and formating the data
a <- read.xlsx('Matriz Energética Nacional ab2014.xlsx', sheetName = 'consolidada tep',
                    rowIndex = 24:49 , colIndex=2:10, header=FALSE) # startRow=4
b <- as.matrix(read.xlsx('Matriz Energética Nacional ab2014.xlsx', sheetName = 'consolidada tep',
                     rowIndex = 2:3, colIndex=2:10, header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)  )
b <- paste0(b[1,],b[2,])
colnames(a) <- b
c <- read.xlsx('Matriz Energética Nacional ab2014.xlsx', sheetName = 'consolidada tep',
           rowIndex = 24:49, colIndex=1:1, header=FALSE,     stringsAsFactors=FALSE) # startRow=4
a <- cbind(c,a)

#converting to long format
a2 <- melt(a,id='X1')[,c(2,1,3)]
colnames(a2) <- c('source','target','value')

#googleVis
g <-   gvisSankey(a2, from="source", 
              to="target", weight="value"      ,
              options=list(
                height=500,
                sankey="{link:{color:{fill:'lightblue'}}}"
              ))

cat(g$html$chart, file="tmp.html")
plot(g)
```

Comment: We cannot replicate your error (if it is an error) because your code implies a reading of an external file we do not have. Post a code that reproduce the error.

Comment: @SabDeM: see the 4th and 5th lines of code. The file is at: https://ben.epe.gov.br/downloads/Matriz%20Energ%c3%a9tica%20Nacional%20ab2014.xlsx

Comment: @SabDeM: I am sorry the download is not fully authomated, download.file() was giving me some other error. tks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excluding the rows with a value of zero yields this result:

```
library(reshape2)
library(googleVis)
library(xlsx)

download.file("https://ben.epe.gov.br/downloads/Matriz%20Energ%c3%a9tica%20Nacional%20ab2014.xlsx", tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx"), mode = "wb")

a <- xlsx::read.xlsx(tf, sheetName = 'consolidada tep', rowIndex = 24:49 , colIndex=2:10, header=FALSE) # startRow=4
b <- as.matrix(xlsx::read.xlsx(tf, sheetName = 'consolidada tep', rowIndex = 2:3, colIndex=2:10, header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)  )
b <- paste0(b[1,],b[2,])
colnames(a) <- b
c <- xlsx::read.xlsx(tf, sheetName = 'consolidada tep', rowIndex = 24:49, colIndex=1:1, header=FALSE,     stringsAsFactors=FALSE) # startRow=4
a <- cbind(c,a)
a2 <- melt(a,id='X1')[,c(2,1,3)]
colnames(a2) <- c('source','target','value')

plot(gvisSankey(subset(a2, value > 0), from="source", to="target", weight="value0", options=list(height=500, sankey="{link:{color:{fill:'lightblue'}}}")))
```

[image]